# submit form by only clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create on my view the submission of a checkbox (it's a toggle of an attribute) by only clicking the checkbox itself, and without having to use the submit button.

This is what I have for my text box/submit:

```
<%= form_for @task, remote: true do |task| %>
    <%= task.check_box :complete, class: "check_box" %>
    <%= task.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I only click the box, I would like to trigger this method:

```
def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    @task.toggle :complete
    @task.save

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

  end
```

I'm wondering if any of you think that creating a link_to with a div would be an easier solution to this problem, otherwise I would like to use jquery or some other method and keep the check box.

Thank you!

Comment: Bind `change` event with `checkbox`es and submit `form` in the event handler.

Comment: I added this to my update.js.erb file but I'm not getting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To to submit form upon selecting checkbox you can simply add `onchange: "this.form.submit();"` and it will submit the form and load the next action.

```
<%= form_for @task, remote: true do |task| %>
  <%= task.check_box :complete, class: "check_box", onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
  Yup I am done!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, see this script for help:

```
$(".check_box").change(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
    $("form").submit();
  }
});
```

You might want to check if the checkbox is being checked **ON** or **OFF**.

Comment: how would I go about finding out if the checkbox is being checked ON or OFF?

Comment: @snovosel, you can use `this.checked `

Comment: I have updated my answer. See this for reference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery?rq=1